# Adding translation in config.xml results in 404

Tags: extensions, configuration, helper

I have tried to add a translation.csv to my module but after adding the lines in the config.xml I can't open my module's backend url anymore (/adminhtml/mymodule results in a 404).

This is what I have added to my config.xml:

```
<adminhtml>
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <Psp_InventoryManager>
                <files>
                  <default>PSP_InventoryManager.csv</default>
                </files>
            </Psp_InventoryManager>
        <modules>
    </translate>
</adminhtml>
```

This is what my config.xml looks like:

**config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Psp_InventoryManager>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Psp_InventoryManager>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <psp_inventorymanager>
                <class>Psp_InventoryManager_Block</class>
            </psp_inventorymanager>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <psp_inventorymanager>
                <class>Psp_InventoryManager_Helper</class>
            </psp_inventorymanager>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <psp_inventorymanager>
                <class>Psp_InventoryManager_Model</class>
            </psp_inventorymanager>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <psp_inventorymanager_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Psp_InventoryManager</module>
                </setup>
            </psp_inventorymanager_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <psp_inventorymanager before="Mage_Adminhtml">Psp_InventoryManager_Adminhtml</psp_inventorymanager>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <psp_inventorymanager>
                    <file>psp/inventorymanager.xml</file>
                </psp_inventorymanager>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Psp_InventoryManager>
                    <files>
                      <default>PSP_InventoryManager.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </Psp_InventoryManager>
            <modules>
        </translate>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<module>` tag is not closed.

See the end of your code:

```
        <modules>
    </translate>
</adminhtml>
```

It should be:

```
        </modules>
    </translate>
</adminhtml>
```

Comment: I don't know how I did not see that, thank you very much! :)